# Using a database information for configuring Unity container

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, dependency-management

Normally, Unity (the DIC) is configured using an standard XML configuration file, such as web.config.

For the purpose of the project, Unity offers great functionality which I would be loving to use. However, since other customers might want to use it, and not all of them will desire to use an XML config file, there is a wish to be able to create adapters, so that the customer can load his/her own configuration the way (s)he wants it.

So, loading the config from a txt, from a custom xml file, from an standard web.config file, or more importantly, from a database schema defined by them, according to their needs. So that all the mappings for the container are on any of those ways.

I was thinking about what was the best way to do this. Probably will end up doing it in a custom way.

Opinions or other tools that compete with Unity that allow this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Unity API lets you do everything you can do in the config file. In fact, the config file loader simply reads the instructions and calls the corresponding API.

My first suggestion would be to consider using the API to configure the container in stead of a config file. Second, if you do want to load config from somewhere else, then simply write a reader for whatever format you want, and call the container API based on what you loaded.

There's nothing in the "box" to read config from other sources, but it's easy to write.

Comment: @Mamsaac If you are looking for an easy way to setup your container you might want to have a look at the [TecX project on codeplex](http://tecx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AdvancedConfigurationEngineForUnity). Among other things it brings an enhanced configuration engine for Unity that supports various conventions for automatic registrations.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use reflection to turn type names, stored as strings in the DB, into `type` instances. Unity can then be configured at application start-up by programatically loading the type mappings into the container.

I don't have VS open at the moment, but I think the syntax would be something like:

```
var mapFrom = typeof(IMyInterface);
var mapTo = Type.GetType("My.App.MyType"); // load the string from the DB
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType(mapFrom, mapTo);
```

---

You might also want to look at [Microsoft MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/).  It doesn't do *exactly* what you are talking about, but it is more designed around plug-in architectures, and being able to just drop different .dlls into a folder and have the app automatically use them.